# Google charts json error

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to create an google char using my json object. i keep getting a error when running `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(Chartdata);`

Please see my code below, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 var Addresses = JSON.parse('{"With Address": 45532627,"Without Address": 10845793}');
        var Age = JSON.parse('{"18-25": 2162586,"26-35": 9995883,"36-45": 9486158,"46-55": 8729677,"56-65": 6913371,"65+": 10545270}');
        var Cellphone = JSON.parse('{"With Cellphone": 21536203,"Without Cellphone": 34842217}');

        google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(Addresses,'Addresses'));
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(Age,'Age'));
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(Cellphone,'Cellphone'));

   function drawChart(Chartdata,name) {           
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(Chartdata);

       var options = {
         title: name,
         pieHole: 0.4,
         legend: 'left'
       };

       var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(name));
       chart.draw(data, options);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first**, `setOnLoadCallback` is meant to be called once, when the page loads
also, `setOnLoadCallback` expects a reference to a `function`, not the result of a `function`

`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`
vs.
`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(Addresses,'Addresses'));`

regardless, the `callback` can be added to the `load` statement

```
google.charts.load("current", {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart(Addresses,'Addresses');
    drawChart(Age,'Age');
    drawChart(Cellphone,'Cellphone');
  },
  packages:["corechart"]
});
```

**next**, in order to create a `DataTable` directly from JSON, it must be in a specific format
found here --> [Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

otherwise, you can load the table manually

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  callback: function () {
    var Addresses = JSON.parse('{"With Address": 45532627,"Without Address": 10845793}');
    var Age = JSON.parse('{"18-25": 2162586,"26-35": 9995883,"36-45": 9486158,"46-55": 8729677,"56-65": 6913371,"65+": 10545270}');
    var Cellphone = JSON.parse('{"With Cellphone": 21536203,"Without Cellphone": 34842217}');

    drawChart(Addresses,'Addresses');
    drawChart(Age,'Age');
    drawChart(Cellphone,'Cellphone');
  },
  packages:["corechart"]
});

function drawChart(Chartdata,name) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

  for (var key in Chartdata) {
    if (Chartdata.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      data.addRow([
        key,
        Chartdata[key]
      ]);
    }
  }

  var options = {
    title: name,
    pieHole: 0.4,
    legend: 'left'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(name));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="Addresses"></div>
<div id="Age"></div>
<div id="Cellphone"></div>
```